# How to connect React to Postgres on Vercel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, postgresql, vercel

This is the error I'm getting.

```
Uncaught (in promise) VercelPostgresError: VercelPostgresError - 'missing_connection_string': You did not supply a 'connectionString' and no 'POSTGRES_URL' env var was found.
```

Here's my code.

cndb.js

```
import { sql, db } from "@vercel/postgres";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    const client = await db.connect({
        POSTGRES_URL: process.env.local.POSTGRES_URL,
    });
    try {
        await client.sql`CREATE TABLE Things (  Name varchar(255), Pass varchar(255) );`;
        const names = ["thinga", "thingb"];
        await client.sql`INSERT INTO Things (Name,Pass) VALUES (${names[0]},${names[1]});`;
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({ error });
    }
    const things = await client.sql`SELECT * FROM Things;`;
    return res.status(200).json({ things });
}
```

page0.js

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState } from "react";

import handler from "./api/cndb";

import "./page0.css";

export function Page0() {
    const [inputvalue, setinputvalue] = useState("");
    return (
        <>
            <div className="Circle" onClick={() => handler(null, null)}>
                submit
            </div>
        <>
    );
}
```

Here's my file structure

[image: Here's my file structure]

I've tried creating .env.local and .env.development.local and .env files which didn`t work for me. In cndb.js I'm not sure if what I have under **const client = await db.connect({})** is correct. I'm also unsure about the way I've called **handle** in **page0.js**. I've tried deploying it to both localhost and vercel.

Also this way of looking at the database **http://localhost:3000/api/cndb** does not work together with react-router-dom and my file structure but I don't know why.

Comment: IMO I don't think `react-router` or your app file structure have anything to do with any postgresql issues. Does the `db.connect` function take an object with a `POSTGRES_URL` key? Does it need a `connectionString` key?

Comment: Hi Drew, I found this **github.com/vercel/storage/tree/main/packages/postgres**, but I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I've been ramming my head against the wall for the past few days, can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables are not loaded from `.env` files on Vercel. You need to add them to your Vercel deployment settings.

[image: Location of the Environment Variables settings on Vercel]

You can add the `POSTGRES_URL` environment variable here, at Your Project -> Settings -> Environment Variables.

Another thing I noticed about your screenshot is that your `.env` file is not being ignored – make sure not to push it to GitHub!

Comment: Thanks for noticing the mistake with the ```.env``` file Daniel. My env variables in vercel settings have been filled up automatically without me realising when i connected the database, so you are right that I shouldn't have been trying to add it as a parameter under ```db.connect```. Unfortunately my code is still not working, I'm getting the same error as before.

Comment: I'm looking at the github repo on @vercel/postgres **https://github.com/vercel/storage/tree/main/packages/postgres**, it says ```// Don't need any custom config?:
import { sql } from '@vercel/postgres';
// `sql` is already set up and ready to go; no further action needed``` this should work on it's own